# Simple Question about Visio 2007 (trying to create a simple UML diagram(C++) )?

Tags: c++, uml, diagram, visio

I'm simply trying to create a UML diagram where I can show the header file declarations.

I to be able to display things such as:

```
Bitmap * getImage()
Coordinate * getCoordinates(Object o)
```

Stuff like that. Problem is, I can't figure out how to display pointers as return types(it only let's be choose objects from the UML diagram) or arguments. I can get around the return types by just including them in the name of the function, but I still can't find out how to display the arguments (ex: `Object o` listed previously) or just find a quick fix around it. I can't quick fix it the same way because Visio automatically puts a parenthesis at the end of my function (ex: `Coordinate * getCoordinates(Object o)` would output `Coordinate * getCoordinates(Object o)()`

Is there a way to enter arguments and parameters that could include pointers? Or a quick fix around it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the method in question in the "Operations" area of the dialog box.  Then click on the "Properties" button to get the "UML Operation Properties" dialog.  In there, set the "suffix" to "*".

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help man. Do you have any idea how to edit the arguments area?

Comment: Alright I figured that part out. I have just one more question. How do I use return types and parameters of classes which are not in my current UML diagram. For example, I want to have the method "Bitmap * getImage()" but I don't have a Bitmap class in my UML diagram

Comment: AFAIK, you need to add the Bitmap class to your diagram, even if you only put in a skeleton.

If you're doing a serious amount of UML modeling, you might look for a "real" UML tool.  I remember the Rational software that used to come with Visual Studio.  It was much more user-friendly and powerful.